# awk bash avg calculation in file

Tags: unix, awk

write the unix command to display roll, name and avg of all students whose score is more than 50 in each subject and average is more than or equal to 75.

avg can be calculated as (subj_1+subj_2)/2.

input:

```
roll ,name,subScore1,subScore2
123,a,88,78
101,b,76,90
812,c,78,98
```

output:

```
123 a 83
812 c 78
```

my code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=',';OFS=' '} {if(NR>1 (&& $3>50 && $4>50) && ($3+$4)/2 >= 75){print $1,$2,($3+$4)/2}}' input_file
```

I don't know why I'm getting error.
please help guys.

Comment: `NR>1 -e` `awk` is not `shell`, it has it's own (different) language. There is no `-e`. What do you mean by `-e`? What should it do?

Comment: yes that typo you can use "&&" instead of -e

Comment: @AkshaySingh, if its a typo then kindly edit your question and correct it please, thank you.

Comment: yes Sir,Question is edited now....

Comment: And one more thing Sir in my solution, is there is bracket problem, because logic wise I have done right ?

Comment: @AkshaySingh, you need not to set `OFS` as space since its default value itself will be space. Logic wise it looks ok but I haven't tested it, also you don't need `&&` in few places which I believe you are already aware of. Thanks for sharing your efforts, keep it up and make sure you always add your efforts in form of code in your questions which is highly encouraged on SO, happy learning.

Comment: Thanks Sir, for your fast feedback as usual, keep us motivated...

Comment: You can't use single quotes in a single-quote-delimted string (including scripts) in any shell. Instead of `awk 'BEGIN {FS=',';OFS=' '}`, syntactically you need `awk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=" "}` (but of course `OFS=" "` isn't actually doing anything as that's the default setting). wrt `if(NR>1 (&& $3>50...` - there's no language I'm aware of where you'd write `cond1 (&& cond2)` instead of `cond1 && (cond2)` just like you did in the rest of your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Adding more generic solution where OP's Input_file could have more than 4 fields/columns in that case one could try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
FNR==1{
  next
}
{
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i>=50){
      ++count
    }
    sum+=$i
  }
  avg=(sum/count)
  if(count==(NF-2) && avg>=75){
    print $1,$2,avg
  }
  count=sum=avg=0
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
FNR==1{
  next
}
avg=($3+$4)/2
avg>=75 && ($3>=50 && $4>=50){
  print $1,$2,avg
}
'  Input_file
```